# How to access Rest API in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

I'm new in rest Api so can any one tell me how to deal with rest API and what delegate methods it requires

Comment: Too general a question, please be a little more specific. What have you tried? REST is simply reading and writing commands using the appropriate HTTP method types. Send a GET HTTP request to read information, POST to write, etc. The normal NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest are perfect for what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library available now:
[RestKIT](http://restkit.org/).